# How to parse lines in file in sequence/match adequate results using python, pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

Here's my code:

```
from pyparsing import *

survey ='''
BREAK_L,PN1000,LA55.16469813,LN18.15054629
PN1,LA54.16469813,LN17.15054629,EL22.222
BREAK_L,PN2000,LA55.16507249,LN18.15125566
PN6,LA54.16506873,LN17.15115798,EL33.333
PN7,LA54.16507249,LN17.15125566,EL44.444
BREAK_L,PN3000,LA55.16507249,LN18.15125566
PN10,LA54.16507522,LN17.15198405,EL55.555
PN11,LA54.16506566,LN17.15139220,EL44.44
PN12,LA54.16517275,LN17.15100652,EL11.111
'''

digits = "0123456789"
number = Word(nums+'.').setParseAction(lambda t: float(t[0]))
num = Word(digits)
text = Word(alphas)
pt_id = Suppress('PN') + Combine(Optional(text) + num + Optional(text) + Optional(num))
separator = Suppress(',')
latitude = Suppress('LA') + number
longitude = Suppress('LN') + number

gps_line = pt_id + separator + latitude + separator + longitude
break_line = (Suppress('BREAK_L,')
          + pt_id
          + separator
          + latitude
          + separator
          + longitude)

result1 = gps_line.scanString(survey)
result2 = break_line.scanString(survey)

for item in result1:
    print item
```

With example above I would like to find solution how to get output like:

gps_line + it's break_line, what means something like in pseudo code:

```
for every gps_line in result1:
    print gps_line + precedent break_line
```

If matter of my question is not clear or not fit to description, feel free to change it.

EDIT #2
What I try to achieve is output:

```
['1', 54.16469813, 17.15054629, 22.222, 'BP1000', 55.16469813, 18.15054629]
['6', 54.16506873, 17.15115798, 33.333, 'BP2000', 55.16507249, 18.15125566]
['7', 54.16507249, 17.15125566, 44.444, 'BP2000', 55.16507249, 18.15125566]
['10', 54.16507522, 17.15198405, 55.555, 'BP3000', 55.16507249, 18.15125566]
['11', 54.16506566, 17.1513922, 44.44, 'BP3000', 55.16507249, 18.15125566]
['12', 54.16517275, 17.15100652, 11.111, 'BP3000', 55.16507249, 18.15125566]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second attempt:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from operator import itemgetter
survey ='''
BREAK_L,PN1000,LA55.16469813,LN18.15054629
PN1,LA54.16469813,LN17.15054629,EL22.222
BREAK_L,PN2000,LA55.16507249,LN18.15125566
PN6,LA54.16506873,LN17.15115798,EL33.333
PN7,LA54.16507249,LN17.15125566,EL44.444
BREAK_L,PN3000,LA55.16507249,LN18.15125566
PN10,LA54.16507522,LN17.15198405,EL55.555
PN11,LA54.16506566,LN17.15139220,EL44.44
PN12,LA54.16517275,LN17.15100652,EL11.111
'''

def parse_line(line):
  brk = False
  kv = {}
  for part in line.split(','):
    if part == 'BREAK_L':
      brk = True
    else:
      k = part[:2]
      v = part[2:]
      kv[k] = v
  return (brk,kv)

def parse_survey(survey):
  ig1 = itemgetter('PN','LA','LN','EL')
  ig2 = itemgetter('PN','LA','LN')
  brk_data = None
  for line in survey.strip().splitlines():
    brk, data = parse_line(line)
    if brk:
      brk_data = data
      continue
    else:
      yield ig1(data) + ig2(brk_data)

for r in parse_survey(survey):
  print r
```

Yields:

```
('1', '54.16469813', '17.15054629', '22.222', '1000', '55.16469813', '18.15054629')
('6', '54.16506873', '17.15115798', '33.333', '2000', '55.16507249', '18.15125566')
('7', '54.16507249', '17.15125566', '44.444', '2000', '55.16507249', '18.15125566')
('10', '54.16507522', '17.15198405', '55.555', '3000', '55.16507249', '18.15125566')
('11', '54.16506566', '17.15139220', '44.44', '3000', '55.16507249', '18.15125566')
('12', '54.16517275', '17.15100652', '11.111', '3000', '55.16507249', '18.15125566')
```

This is really not much different to my previous attempt. I'd already paired the data for you. I assume you'll be able to change `1000` into `BP1000` yourself.

Comment: I tend to avoid pyparsing when the subject data is readily machine readable.

Comment: My desired result is just 'copy and paste' compilation of two independent loops: for item in result1, for item in result2. Sorry if it is misleading but I just wanted to present ilustrating example output.

Comment: My input[survey='''...'''] is just siplified example I created for the purposes of this question.

Comment: Oh, so your sample input isn't the same as the data that produced your sample output!?

Comment: Well, it is the same but It is taken from two independent loops like: for x in result1:print x and then for y in result2: print y, then I matched it manually for purposes of example.

Comment: So, `44,84` is part of the `pyparsing` results (offsets perhaps)? Does my suggested answer help you with your problem?

Comment: Your answer helped me as an agile approach to parsing at all, so thaks, I am just beginner and apreciate every tip. But my problem is still unsolved; my original input is in fact quite complex, that's why I use pyparsing.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's my fault, to many misleading informations from my side. Please, take a look at my EDIT #2, I need exactly that output. Thanks a lot for your attention.